# How to add Instruction image to the app in Android

Tags: java, android, html, frameworks

How to add a instruction image to the new Android application, Onclick it should disable it should not appear on reopening the app.pls Help me am new to Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple solution would be to show a dialog with your instructions. This dialog should also have an "OK. Got it. Don't show again" (you get the idea) button.

Use SharedPreferences to save if the user has clicked the "OK" button. Only show the dialog if that has not happened yet.